# Efeito texto ou paragrafo carregando

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ola.

Venho observando em varios sites. Facebook, Dropbox e varios frameworks que usam css e js um efeito que aparece antes do texto ser carregado. Espero que entendam. Obrigado [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso é uma técnica utilizada na experiência do usuário. Um ótimo artigo chamado **[The Illusion of Time](https://medium.com/swlh/the-illusion-of-time-8f321fa2f191#.3x0i9irmu)** (A Ilusão do Tempo) explica muito bem sobre como a percepção humana do tempo pode ser "driblada" utilizando de recursos simples como um gif animado, veja o exemplo do Facebook abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A construção desse recurso depende de qual framework ou biblioteca que você está utilizando em seu projeto.

O artigo [Facebook content placeholder deconstruction](https://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html) (Desconstrução do placeholder de conteúdo do Facebook) demonstra como é feito essa técnica desconstruindo a mesma utilizada pelo Facebook.

Comment: legal +1 esse eu não conhecia ...